# WPF Collapsible Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am trying to implement a collapsible listview to Master-Detail Collection (e.g Order-OrderDetails), by following the http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/, without success. My goal is to expand the Listview row (Order) and show all OrderDetail entries upon user row selection.

```
public class Order 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber{ get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
public class OrderDetail 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public double Cost{ get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Post your XAML as well.

Comment: It is just a copy of the above article....

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well I am looking for sample code or guidance on how to implement the above feature. I am sorry if I am not clear.